# Delete textarea previously inserted in a shape

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, text-on-path

I wanted to create text that follows a path in illustrator. I thought this would be achieved by selecting the text tool and clicking on the circle (see picture). However, this created a textarea and these two little squares that looks like an anchor point appeared, as shown.

[image]

I think these show that is a textarea and are used to insert text ragged left or right (am I wrong?)
However, how do I delete the textarea to turn it back into a simple shape? Thank you!

Comment: Is there a reason why you can not undo

Comment: No reason, joojaa. I just want to be prepared for the future in case of more complex shapes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just hit <kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd> the shape, copy to clipboard, delete the shape and paste in place via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>. This would basicly remove the initial shape and replace it with a clean one in the same place.

Probably best to do this in Outline mode, that's via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Lucian! It looks like the best way to proceed. Just a question, since we are already here: wht is keyline mode? Thank you!

Comment: What i meant was 'Outline' mode under 'View' in the main menu. That displays the artwork in a _shape only_ view without any other formatting so you can work easier with complex shapes. Try the shortcut with your file open.

Comment: @Lucian why is this not the way you would do it?

Comment: @joojaa. not sure i understand your question

Comment: i mean why do you say one can not. When you in fact what you are doing is removing the text form the object.  Offcousre it can not reverse to the state it had before but tahst a different thing.